# Pentaho Kettle: list of remote Carte objects IDs from Java

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I already know how to run and attach a transformation running on a remote Carte server using Java given transformation's Carte Object ID:

```
KettleEnvironment.init();
TransMeta transMeta = new TransMeta("file.ktr");
Trans trans = new Trans(transMeta);
SlaveServer ss = new SlaveServer("test", IP, PORT, "cluster", "cluster");
TransExecutionConfiguration jec = new TransExecutionConfiguration();
jec.setRemoteServer(ss);
String carteObjectId = trans.sendToSlaveServer(transMeta, jec, null, null);
```

and

```
KettleEnvironment.init();
SlaveServer ss = new SlaveServer("test", IP, PORT, "cluster", "cluster");
SlaveServerTransStatus state = ss.getTransStatus(transMetaName, carteObjectId, 0);
List<StepStatus> list = state.getStepStatusList();
```

However, for a more general (and usable) remote monitoring I need to get the whole list of the Object IDs of the running/run transformations on the remote Carte server. Which methods can I use to get such a list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SlaveServerTransStatus> transStatus = slave1.getStatus().getTransStatusList();
for(SlaveServerTransStatus transStatu:transStatus){
    System.out.println(transStatu.getTransName()+"--"+transStatu.getStatusDescription()+"---"+transStatu.getId());
}
```

Comment: While this code may help answer the question , some additional explanation would be helpful to future readers.